# is it possible to use google photos in lollipop (sdk version 22)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, google-photos, google-photos-api

" I need to open google photos login and download required images in to device ", but ** my device is in lollipop ** .

I think google services are available from sdk version 23.

is there any reference or idea to use google photos in lollipop .

Thanks
Venkatesh

Comment: In general, devices running Android 4.1 (API level 16) or later and have the Google Play services app installed receive updates within a few days. See [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview)

Comment: hi majuran : Thanks for quick replay.  when i tried to build google photos api ,it prompt to change the sdk version to "23 " .then how can i build google photos in lollipop(22)